# Google play keeps rejecting my app to not adhering for google play developer program policies

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, ads, playback

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELfXN.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFxfp.jpg)iam using a later sdk version than the 4.0.1 he asking me to use but still rejecting my app any help would be usefull

I tried to change the sdk version and the api used but nothing changed

Comment: provide more detail about rejection

Comment: Issue with your app 
Your app is using the Unity SDK which collects but may not be limited to Android ID and Advertising ID identifiers. Persistent device identifiers may not be linked to other personal and sensitive user data or resettable device identifiers.
You may consider moving to another SDK; removing this SDK; or if available from your SDK provider, upgrading to a policy-compliant version of this SDK that does not include the violating code.

According to the information provided by your SDK provider, you may consider upgrading to 4.0.1

Comment: This is the message thay sent me

Answer (score 0):

Google play store reject application who are using Unity SDk.if you are using Unity SDK make sure that the SDK updated.I think Unity Updated own SDK after confilt with Google Play Console.

Comment: Thanks for answering , iam using unity skd but higher version ,iam using 4.3 , if not using unity sdk how else iam gonna apply ads